# An error happen when using UIimagePickerController

Tags: ios, ipad, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

Code：

```
-(BOOL) startMediaBrowser:(GSAvatarSettingView *)sender{
if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO)) {
    return NO;
}

UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

cameraUI.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
cameraUI.allowsEditing = YES;
cameraUI.delegate = self;
[cameraUI.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

[self presentViewController:cameraUI animated:NO completion:^{}];

return  YES;
}
```

Error：
Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.
2014-12-31 09:25:26.437 [5260:1316105] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.
2014-12-31 09:25:26.439 GSStudent[5260:1316105] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I heard its a bug. I am not sure though. Just check the privacy settings of your device, and check if the camera access to your app is blocked or not.

Otherwise your code looks just fine, you even checked the availability of camera. Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Can you tell more information about the  privacy settings.the camera access to the  app is not blocked, and can take photo.